# Hide video controls on HTML5 video tag on mobile Fullscreen mode (iOS/Android)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to hide some controls on demand while the video is on **fullscreen** state.

I've been trying to accomplish this on my iPhone 14 Pro (iOS 16.2) for days now without success, tried many ways through `controls` and `disablePictureInPicture` on the DOM element itself and also the CSS way but no matter what I do, it will always show the native iOS video controls. Even if in desktop browser (Chrome) works, it won't work on a real device. What am I missing?

It also pauses the content as soon as you exit fullscreen. Now I see this happens even on apps like YouTube, Twitch, etc whenever you open them from the browser.

Here's an example on [codepen](https://codepen.io/msqar/pen/bGjJevR)

Or if you want to run it here

```js
window.addEventListener("load", () => {
  const btn = document.getElementsByClassName("button")[0];
  btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
    const container = document.getElementsByTagName(
      "video"
    )[0];
    if (container.requestFullscreen) {
      container.requestFullscreen();
    } else if (container.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
      container.webkitRequestFullscreen();
    } else if (container.webkitEnterFullscreen) {
      container.webkitEnterFullscreen();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.video-container-layout {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
}

video::-webkit-media-controls-container {
  opacity: 0 !important;
}

*::-webkit-media-controls-panel {
  display: none!important;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}
    /* Old shadow dom for play button */
*::--webkit-media-controls-play-button {
    display: none!important;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}
    /* New shadow dom for play button */
    /* This one works */
*::-webkit-media-controls-start-playback-button {
    display: none!important;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="video-container-layout">
    <video id="video" width="400" autoplay loop mute="true">
  <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support HTML video.
</video>
  </div>
  <button class="button">Fullscreen</button>
</main>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following CSS ruleset to hide it on iOS:

```css
video::-webkit-media-controls-start-playback-button {
    display: none;
}
```